# Accesing parent cell labels swift

Tags: ios, swift, parent, uitableview

I have a button placed inside a `TableViewCell`, the button triggers a action which passes data to another `ViewController` and displays it. Is there any way to access the labels of the particular cell that I clicked?

The cells are being created and populated from an API.

For example, I have 10 cells, all having different labels inside. I need to access the labels of the cell that I clicked (Or the cell that the button I clicked on is a child to) and pass this data to my other `ViewController`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by giving the button tag an ID from my API and passing this to the other `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

That works, I had just figured this out:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let cell = self.historyViewTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) 
        println(cell.cellLabel.text!)
    }
```